# How to get window controls back for document in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a document, one in particular, that tends to be edited by a lot of contributors with varying versions of Office. This document when opened in Excel 2007 does not open into an MDI window with the full set of controls, but is instead in a fixed size window. How can this be resolved?

See screenshot, ignore the blacked out content:

[image: Fixed window issue]

Comment: Which version of Office are you using? Looks like 2010.

Comment: No, that's 2007, as the title says.

Comment: Agreed, that's my answer, cheers Jeff!